# How to get profile picture of youtube channel without using any key

Tags: wordpress, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

i used this code where i get youtube subscribe button,profile image and channel title without using any keys .but i want only profile picture and in one case only channel title, but unable to style it.i find there is a way by using youtube data API but it requires API key i want a method without key.

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js"></script>
<div class="g-ytsubscribe" data-channel="GoogleDevelopers" data-layout="default" data-count="default"></div>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When using the YouTube API, you must have an API key. Getting an API key is easy and free. Here's how you do it.

1. Go to the [Google APIs page](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/library) and create a new project (If you don't already have one). Click the project button in the top left side, then click "Create project" and follow the steps
2. Go to the [YouTube Data API](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/library/youtube.googleapis.com?q=youtube%20data) and enable it for your project
3. Go to the “Credentials” tab in the menu to the left
4. Click on "Create credentials" and select “API key”

Now you're finished and you have your API key you can use with the YouTube Data Api. I hope that helps!